# How to use if and elseif in wordpress without getting error

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to show content based on URL in the wordpress category pages, so this will help me to have some content on the category page other than just posts.

website : https://www.1govtjob.com

This following code works fine without any issues.

```
<?php if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/category/tamilnadu-govt-jobs/' ) { ?>
<p class="top_para">This page is dedicated to Tamilnadu Government Job Alerts.</p>
<?php } ?>

<?php if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/category/central-govt-jobs/' ) { ?>
<p class="top_para">This page is dedicated to Central Government Job Alerts.</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Im trying to use elseif statement instead of using multiple if statement for each category page.

If i use this following code, i end up getting this error

```
<?php if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/category/tamilnadu-govt-jobs/' ) { ?>
<p class="top_para">This page is dedicated to Tamilnadu Government Job Alerts.</p>
<?php } ?>

<?php elseif( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/category/central-govt-jobs/' ) { ?>
<p class="top_para">This page is dedicated to Central Government Job Alerts.</p>
<?php } ?>
```

[image]

Comment: is the `$_SERVER` variable available? The error might be an undefined index error. Try `if( ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?? '') == '/category/tamilnadu-govt-jobs/' )` and check if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work. There should be no closing tags between your closing **}** and the **elseif**.

Try this:

```
<?php if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/category/tamilnadu-govt-jobs/' ) { ?>
<p class="top_para">This page is dedicated to Tamilnadu Government Job Alerts.</p>

<?php } elseif( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/category/central-govt-jobs/' ) { ?>

<p class="top_para">This page is dedicated to Central Government Job Alerts.</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to keep opening and closing PHP tags. Simply stay inside of PHP the whole time.

```
<?php 
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/category/tamilnadu-govt-jobs/' ) {
     echo '<p class="top_para">This page is dedicated to Tamilnadu Government Job Alerts.</p>';
} elseif( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/category/central-govt-jobs/' ) {
     echo '<p class="top_para">This page is dedicated to Central Government Job Alerts.</p>';
}
```

Comment: are you sure this works? i don't see any closing php statement? <?php ?>

Comment: The closing tag has not been needed for a very long time. Given the context of the question and not knowing exactly where it is being used the answer is correct. It is actually recommended that a closing tag NOT be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:
`<?php if($condition): ?>
    <p> html text/code </p>
    <?php echo "in if"; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <p> Some html code </p> <!-- or -->
    <?php echo "in else"; ?>
<?php endif;?>`

Answer (score 0):

I Think the best way to write if-else if-else statement in php :

```
<?php if(): ?>
   Some Html Code Here.....
<?php else if(): ?>
   Some Html Code Here.....
<?php endif; ?>
```

You Can Learn More On : https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: It would be great if you could explain what was wrong in the original code instead of only suggesting an alternative format without explaining that